# Can 2 smartphones malfunction if they are hold together in the pocket for long times everyday?

Tags: network-signal

I apologize for my ignorance but I am not very tech savvy. 
Basically  I do  a field job and I always have 2 phones in one of those bags you put around your waist.

I had 2 Samsung galaxy S2 in the past and after a while they started having trouble with receiving signal. I went to a "specialized" shop where they sell smartphones and the guy told me that the malfunctions is caused by keeping them together for prolonged periods of times.And went on with some speech about electromagnetism.

Now the two S2 were malfunctioning for real as I tried with different sim cards, factory resets and the problem persisted.

I then bought a S3 and yesterday I bought another one. I always need 2 phones..long story.

Now some other people basically confirmed that keeping them close to each other breaks them but none of them,in my opinion, seemed to know their shit.

so,

Can 2 smartphones malfunction if they are hold together in the pocket for long times everyday?